# Object from a value in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I encounter a difficulty, I put the GitHub link to you so you can see the code if you want to help: https://github.com/Bromy74/ChoixResto

I'm trying to make a restaurant reservation form.

Let me explain: the form asks for the name of the restaurant (in a DropDownList that contains all the names of the "Resto" type objects), the number of participants, the date of the event and the name of the organizer (in a DropDownList that contains all the names of the "User" objects)

When I click on the validation button of the form, I would like the action produced to fill in the "Booking" table of my database using the information on the form.

I put some elements:

Booking Class :

```
public class Booking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Resto Restochoisi { get; set; }
    public int Nbpeople { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public  Utilisateur Orga { get; set; }
}
```

Part of the BookingController :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var context = new BddContexte();

    var vm = new BookingViewModel()
    {
        Restos = new SelectList(context.Restos.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Nom"),
        Utilisateurs = new SelectList(context.Utilisateurs.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Prenom")

    };

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Resto restochoisi, int nbpeople, DateTime datepicker, Utilisateur orga)
{
    int id = dal.CreerBooking(restochoisi, nbpeople, datepicker, orga);
    return View();
}
```

Part of the Index View :

```
@Html.DropDownList("restochoisi", Model.Restos, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("nbpeople", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
<input name="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
@Html.DropDownList("orga", Model.Utilisateurs, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And the methode "CreerBooking" :

```
public int CreerBooking(Resto Restochoisi,int Nbpeople,DateTime Date, Utilisateur Orga)
{
    Booking booking = new Booking { Restochoisi = Restochoisi, Nbpeople = Nbpeople, Date = Date, Orga = Orga };

    bdd.Bookings.Add(booking);
    bdd.SaveChanges();
    return booking.Id;
}
```

In fact I don't know how to recover the object of type "Resto" from the DropDownList, and then create the object of type "Booking"

Thank you in advance to those who will take the time to help me!
Matthieu

Comment: It doesn't work like this... You would typically select the ID number (or Primary Key) of the object, and then use this to look the object up...

Comment: Ok, i tried like this, but I didnt know how to select the object when I have the ID ? Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: Your `Index()` POST method parameters need to be `int restochoisi` and `int orga` (assuig that is the type of your `Id` properties) - a `<select>` posts back a simple value, not a complex object.

Comment: Ok so now, I have this :

             `public ActionResult Index(int restochoisi, int nbpeople, DateTime datepicker, int orga)
     {
          //??
          int id = dal.CreerBooking(***, nbpeople, datepicker, ***);
          return View();
     }`

And how can I select the objet Resto which have "restochoisi" as ID ?

Comment: Just get it from the database.